# Connect three computers (including one laptop) to one monitor

Tags: laptop, switch, desktop-computer, kvm-switch, docking-station

I have the following hardware:

- 2 Desktop PCs, running Windows XP and Ubuntu
- Macbook Pro
- a LCD monitor, a wired keyboard, and a wired mouse

Currently, I'm using an oldish IOGear KVM switch to connect the two PCs to the input/output (and it works very well).

I'd like a setup that includes the laptop as well, ideally maintaining as much portability as possible (meaning I'd like to be able to sit down, easily plug in my laptop, work on all computers, then easily pick up and leave with the laptop - is *docking station* the right word here?). What hardware do I need to do this?

Answer (score 1):

They sell 4 port KVM switches also. So i would suggest getting a 4 port KVM, *and* a docking station for the laptop.

Comment: Is there anything else I need besides the docking station? (Cords, cables, etc.?)

Answer (score 0):

Well  - if your monitor has an extra hdmi slot, then you could connect the mac to that, right?  I dont have enough rep to add a comment, or I would - sorry if this does not help.

Answer (score 0):

A docking station specific to your laptop and a KVM switch that allows more than two connections.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the laptop.  Most business class laptops have the ability to use a docking station which you could cable into the KVM and do exactly what you want (assuming that the KVM you have will support 3 sources,  common multiple are 2,4,16).  If your laptop doesn't support a docking station, then you are looking at plugging cables into the laptop every time you want to "dock" it.  I've seen USB "port replicators" that claim to be able to connect your Keyboard, mouse, speakers, and Video with a single USB cable, but I've never used one, so I cannot vouch for them.